# Firebase dynamic link opens app but onCreate for the Listening activity not called (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I trying to integrate Firebase dynamic links to my app (which uses no other firebase components currently). I went through all the steps given in the documentation and but I am not able to receive the deep link using the

```
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink);
```

More over, I'm trying to log and display a toast on the onCreate of the activity the intent filter is attached to, but looks like even the oncreate doesn't get called. If I remove the intent filter, the dynamic link opens my Launcher activity instead.
This is how I have added an intent filter

```
<activity android:name=".receiver.DynamicLinkReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="licsuperagent.com" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="licsuperagent.com" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The only Log message that comes through is,

```
com.xx.xx D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you enable **AppInvite.API** on API console.

Comment: There could be something wrong with your url. Get the long version from your Firebase console and investigate it. If you don't see any problem, add it to your question here.

Comment: It was a problem with the google-services.json file that I downloaded had an error with the package name. Sorry for wasting your valuable time.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as solved @HaranSivaram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of using the google-services.json file generated for the release build package, but I was using the same file in my dev build.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Anyone having the same problem, just need to create another google-services.json file from Firebase for your dev build package.